# Calculating Hourly Bonus

Tags: excel, vba

I'm writing a function to return bonus value

I was trying to pass hours as input

```
Function CalculateBonus(workedhours As Variant) As Variant
    CalculateBonus= TimeValue(workedhours) / TimeValue("30:00:00")
End Function
```

when 30:00 is passed, it should return 1, when 45:00 is passed, it should return 1.5

Comment: `workedhours/1.25` should work OK. 30h = 1.25days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're passing the time in as a string in "HH:mm" format, you could use something like:

```
Function CalculateBonus(workedhours As String) As Double

    Dim hours As Integer, minutes As Integer

    hours = Left(workedhours, InStr(1, workedhours, ":") - 1)
    minutes = Right(workedhours, Len(workedhours) - InStr(1, workedhours, ":"))

    CalculateBonus = (hours * 60 + minutes) / 1800

End Function
```

Comment: my input will be like 1:00 or 30:00 format. to say simply, it will be in hrs:mns format